# Need help getting signals to work with inventory so I can interact with item slots

Tags: godot, godot4

I need help figuring out how to get signals to work with my inventory system so that I can click and interact with items in the inventory window. I've got it where it is CORRECTLY showing my test player's inventory items in the window, and yet, I'm trying to follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V79YabQZC1s&t=1255s but when my player's inventory (that I've checked is set correctly even as it is connecting to the signal) is connected to the signal. When the signal gets trigged, self (inventory data self) is a blank inventory data set and not my test player's inventory data set. If anyone can help. I would greatly appreciate it! I've just started learning Godot (the engine and GodotScript), so I'm probably just missing something simple. But it's driving me crazy. Thanks for any assistance!

Inventory Data class:

```
extends Resource
class_name InventoryData

signal inventory_interact(inventory_data: InventoryData, index: int, button: int)

@export var slot_datas: Array[SlotData]


func remove_item(slot: SlotData) -> bool:

    return true
    
    
func add_item(slot: SlotData) -> bool:
    return true
    
func on_slot_clicked(index: int, button: int) -> void:
    inventory_interact.emit(self, index, button)
    
func grab_slot_data(index: int) -> SlotData:
    var slot_data = slot_datas[index]
    
    if slot_data:
        return slot_data
    else:
        return null
```

slot node script:

```
extends PanelContainer

signal slot_clicked(index: int, button: int)

func set_slot_data(slot_data: SlotData) -> void:
    var item_icon: TextureRect = $MarginContainer/ItemIcon
    var quantity_label: Label = $QuantityLabel
    if slot_data:       
        var item_data = slot_data.item_data
        item_icon.texture = item_data.item_icon
        tooltip_text = "%s\n%s" % [item_data.name, item_data.description]
        
        if slot_data.quantity > 1:
            quantity_label.text = "x%s" % slot_data.quantity
            quantity_label.show()


func _on_gui_input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if event is InputEventMouseButton \
        and (event.button_index == MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT \
        or event.button_index == MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT) \
        and event.is_pressed():
            slot_clicked.emit(get_index(), event.button_index)
```

slots block (the block of slots which go into the inventory window for each inventory tab)

```
extends MarginContainer


const SLOT = preload("res://inventory/slot.tscn")


func _ready() -> void:
    pass

func set_slots_block_data(inv_data: InventoryData, item_type_filter: ItemData.ITEMTYPE) -> void:
    
    var passed_inv_data: Array[SlotData] = inv_data.slot_datas

    #optional item type filter
    match int(item_type_filter):
        int(ItemData.ITEMTYPE.EQUIPPABLE):
            passed_inv_data = inv_data.slot_datas.filter(func(x): return not x or x.item_data.item_type == ItemData.ITEMTYPE.EQUIPPABLE)
            passed_inv_data.sort_custom(func(a,b): return a != null and b == null)
        int(ItemData.ITEMTYPE.FOOD):
            passed_inv_data = inv_data.slot_datas.filter(func(x): return not x or x.item_data.item_type == ItemData.ITEMTYPE.FOOD)
            passed_inv_data.sort_custom(func(a,b): return a != null and b == null)
        int(ItemData.ITEMTYPE.USABLE):
            passed_inv_data = inv_data.slot_datas.filter(func(x): return not x or x.item_data.item_type == ItemData.ITEMTYPE.USABLE)
            passed_inv_data.sort_custom(func(a,b): return a != null and b == null)
        int(ItemData.ITEMTYPE.QUEST):
            passed_inv_data = inv_data.slot_datas.filter(func(x): return not x or x.item_data.item_type == ItemData.ITEMTYPE.QUEST)
            passed_inv_data.sort_custom(func(a,b): return a != null and b == null)
        int(ItemData.ITEMTYPE.MISC):
            passed_inv_data = inv_data.slot_datas.filter(func(x): return not x or x.item_data.item_type == ItemData.ITEMTYPE.MISC)
            passed_inv_data.sort_custom(func(a,b): return a != null and b == null)

    #put in empty slots for the ones filtered out so the array is the same size as the one passed in
    var diff: int = inv_data.slot_datas.size() - passed_inv_data.size()
    var empt: Array[SlotData]
    empt.resize(diff)
    
    passed_inv_data.append_array(empt)
    
    inv_data.slot_datas = passed_inv_data
            
    populate_item_grid(inv_data)


func populate_item_grid(inventory_data: InventoryData) -> void:
    var item_grid = $"ScrollContainer/MarginContainer/ItemGrid"
    var children = item_grid.get_children()
    
    if children:
        
        for child in children:
            child.queue_free()
        
        for slot_data in inventory_data.slot_datas:
            var slot = SLOT.instantiate()       
            item_grid.add_child(slot)
            
            slot.slot_clicked.connect(inventory_data.on_slot_clicked)
            
            if slot_data:   
                slot.set_slot_data(slot_data)

                    


func _on_inventory_window_close_requested() -> void:
    pass # Replace with function body.
```

Inventory Sub Screen (the actual inventory part of the inventory screen - a part of the actual inventory screen I am saving for an equipment system.)

```
extends PanelContainer

const SLOTS_BLOCK = preload("res://inventory/inventory_slots_block.tscn")

var test_inv = preload("res://test_objects/test_inventory.tres")
var slotdatas = test_inv.slot_datas

@onready var tabs: TabContainer = $HBoxContainer/MarginContainer/VBoxContainer/InventoryTabContainer


# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready() -> void:      
    pass
    


func set_inventory_panel(inv: InventoryData) -> void:
    #this was the only way I could find to get the tab names to work right. Stupid tab containersr
        
    if inv:
        var invall: Control = $HBoxContainer/MarginContainer/VBoxContainer/InventoryTabContainer/All
        var childrenall = invall.get_children()
        for c in childrenall:
            self.remove_child(c)
            c.queue_free()
        var inv_panel_all = SLOTS_BLOCK.instantiate()
        inv_panel_all.set_slots_block_data(inv, ItemData.ITEMTYPE.NULL)
        invall.add_child(inv_panel_all) 
        
        var inveq: Control = $HBoxContainer/MarginContainer/VBoxContainer/InventoryTabContainer/Equippable
        var childreneq = inveq.get_children()
        for c in childreneq:
            self.remove_child(c)
            c.queue_free()
        var inv_panel_equip= SLOTS_BLOCK.instantiate()
        inv_panel_equip.set_slots_block_data(inv, ItemData.ITEMTYPE.EQUIPPABLE)
        inveq.add_child(inv_panel_equip)
        
        var invus: Control = $HBoxContainer/MarginContainer/VBoxContainer/InventoryTabContainer/Usable
        var childrenus = invus.get_children()
        for c in childrenus:
            self.remove_child(c)
            c.queue_free()
        var inv_panel_use= SLOTS_BLOCK.instantiate()
        inv_panel_use.set_slots_block_data(inv, ItemData.ITEMTYPE.USABLE)
        invus.add_child(inv_panel_use)
        
        var invq: Control = $HBoxContainer/MarginContainer/VBoxContainer/InventoryTabContainer/Quest
        var childrenq = invq.get_children()
        for c in childrenq:
            self.remove_child(c)
            c.queue_free()
        var inv_panel_q= SLOTS_BLOCK.instantiate()
        inv_panel_q.set_slots_block_data(inv, ItemData.ITEMTYPE.QUEST)
        invq.add_child(inv_panel_q)
        
        var invfood: Control = $HBoxContainer/MarginContainer/VBoxContainer/InventoryTabContainer/Food
        var childrenfood = invfood.get_children()
        for c in childrenfood:
            self.remove_child(c)
            c.queue_free()
        var inv_panel_food= SLOTS_BLOCK.instantiate()
        inv_panel_food.set_slots_block_data(inv, ItemData.ITEMTYPE.FOOD)
        invfood.add_child(inv_panel_food)
```

Actual Inventory Screen:

```
extends Window

const INVSUBSCREEN = preload("res://inventory/inventory_sub_screen.tscn")

var test_inv = preload("res://test_objects/test_inventory.tres")
var grabbed_slot_data: SlotData

func _ready() -> void:
    pass


func _on_close_requested() -> void:
    self.queue_free()
    
    
func set_inventory_panel(inv: InventoryData) -> void:
    var children = self.get_children()
    for c in children:
        self.remove_child(c)
        c.queue_free()
    var invp = INVSUBSCREEN.instantiate()
    inv.inventory_interact.connect(on_inventory_interact)
    invp.set_inventory_panel(inv)
    self.add_child(invp)
    
func on_inventory_interact(inventory_data: InventoryData,
 index: int, button: int) -> void:
    
    match [grabbed_slot_data, button]:
        #if no slot data grabbed yet and left mouse button is pressed
        [null, MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT]:
            grabbed_slot_data = inventory_data.grab_slot_data(index)
    print(grabbed_slot_data)
```

Main screen main script:

```
extends Control


const BEGGAR_ENCOUNTER = preload("res://image_panel_images/beggar_encounter_image2.png")
const INTRO_IMG = preload("res://image_panel_images/start_image.png")
const INVPANEL = preload("res://inventory/inventory.tscn")
const START_PLAYER = preload("res://character/characters/start_player.tres")

@onready var image: Node = $PanelContainer/MarginContainer/MainColumns/ImagePanel/MainImage
@onready var health_manager: Node = $Scripts/HealthIconManagement
@onready var current_player: Node = $Scripts/CurrentPlayer
@onready var sub_windows: Node = $SubWindows


func _ready() -> void:
    
    image.texture = INTRO_IMG
    health_manager.set_health_to_full()
    current_player.set_character(START_PLAYER)
    
    
func _on_btn_settings_pressed() -> void:
    #settings window
    pass


func _on_button_inventory_pressed() -> void:
    var inv_panel = INVPANEL.instantiate()
    var current_player_character = current_player.character
    inv_panel.set_inventory_panel(current_player.character.inv)
    sub_windows.add_child(inv_panel)
```

Let me know if anyone needs screenshots or something of my node trees or anything. Thank you!